# Invisible White space in string(url) after concatenating a variable

Tags: php

I have a URL where i want to change the arguments dynamically. But when i append the variable to the URL i found a invisible white space in the url.

This is the URL after concatenating the variable

https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/﻿**513375.BO**?formatted=true&crumb=d6UeK6BIz2v&lang=en-IN&region=IN&modules=summaryProfile%2CfinancialData%2CrecommendationTrend%2CupgradeDowngradeHistory%2Cearnings%2CdefaultKeyStatistics%2CcalendarEvents%2CesgScores&corsDomain=in.finance.yahoo.com

There is a hidden space before the **513375.BO** in the URL that causes error. I have few ways like preg_replace(), utf_encode(), trim()

```
$string = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/'.trim($ex_token).'.BO?formatted=true&crumb=d6UeK6BIz2v&lang=en-IN&region=IN&modules=summaryProfile%2CfinancialData%2CrecommendationTrend%2CupgradeDowngradeHistory%2Cearnings%2CdefaultKeyStatistics%2CcalendarEvents%2CesgScores&corsDomain=in.finance.yahoo.com';
$url = htmlentities($string, null, 'utf-8');
$url = str_replace(" ", "", $url);
$url = html_entity_decode($url);
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

The hidden space is either in `$ex_token` or in the string in your script file. It is not being inserted by concatenation, `trim()`, `htmlentities()`, `str_replace()` or `html_entity_decode()`.

Try using `var_dump()` or `strlen()` to check the string length and see if it is as long as you think it is.